# android bluetooth client and server running at the same time

Tags: android, bluetooth

Is it possible to have a Bluetooth server and client running at the same time?
I need this to enable chaining devices. For example to send a message from one device to a second one over a third that acts as client for one and server for the second.

Comment: This can be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950588/adapting-android-bluetooth-chat-for-multiple-devices

Comment: Thanks for the tip but this can be just one server with two clients connected to it. I would like to add more devices to the line

Answer (score 0):

Yes as of Bluetooth v4.1 this is possible, and most current Android devices support Bluetooth v4.1. See these links below for more information:-

- [Bluetooth Peripheral Central Role Possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53005275/2215147)
- [Concurrent Central and Peripheral Role with Bluetooth](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/420273/30489)
- [Can Android Devices Run BLE Central and Peripheral at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37024547/can-android-device-run-bluetooth-le-in-peripheral-and-central-modes-at-the-same)